# PHP form is not transferring all data via $_POST method

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

Currently, I am trying to delete multiple items with checkboxes using a form and $_POST method in PHP. However, when I submit the form I only receive the value of a submit button and none of the checkbox values.

So first of all, I have an index.html.php file (template file), where my submit button is located (last nav-item).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid border-bottom m-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Product List</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary mx-2" href="#">Add</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <input type="submit" value="Mass Delete" name="deleteProducts" form="deleteForm" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <?=$output?>
    </div>
</main>
```

Then I output all of the products and a form (the form is located at the bottom), onto the page:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <div class="card my-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['sku'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></p>
            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></p>
            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['price'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '$'?></p>

            <?php if (!is_null($product['size'])): ?>
            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo 'Size: ' . htmlspecialchars($product['size'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' MB'?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!is_null($product['dimensions'])): ?>
            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo 'Dimensions: ' . htmlspecialchars($product['dimensions'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!is_null($product['weight'])): ?>
            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo 'Weight: ' . htmlspecialchars($product['weight'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' KG'?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <form action="deleteproducts.php" method="post" class="text-center" id="deleteForm">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="text-center" value="<?=$product['sku']?>"> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And lastly, I try to delete items that were checked on the previous page with this code:

```
    $ids = array();

    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $pval) {
        $ids[] = (int)$pval;
    }

    $ids = implode(',', $ids);

    $query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `sku` IN ( $ids )");
    $query->execute();

    header('location: index.php');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $title = 'An error has occured';

    $output = 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine();
}
```

However, I get the message that: **Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\scandiweb\deleteproducts.php**

So what could be the reason that nothing is being transferred via the POST method except the value of a submit button itself.

Comment: Only inputs within the `<form>.... </form>` tags are sent when you click the submit button. You only have the checkbox in the form tags and no submit button by the looks of it

Comment: Its not clear how you actually submit the (whatever)

Comment: Well, my submit button (on the first snippet, has the same ID as my form, so they should be linked together). If not is there any other way to connect a submit button, that is outside the form, with the form itself? Because I need the submit button to stay at the top, while all the checkboxes are generated with the foreach loop

Comment: not related to your current question, but you’ll want to put the test for delete at the **top** of your script, before any output. and also exit or die after the redirect. kudos on the redirect; most posters here don’t do that.

Comment: encapsulate all iterated content in a single form tag, change submit button to plain button, and use javascript to trigger form submit on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how forms work.

Your idea that naming things the same will somehow link them together is wrong. The `id` attribute should be unique on the page. Browsers won't assemble a big form from several small ones with the same `id`.

From the HTML you've posted you're creating something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Mass Delete" name="deleteProducts" form="deleteForm" class="btn btn-primary">

<form action="deleteproducts.php" method="post" class="text-center" id="deleteForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="text-center" value="<?=$product['sku']?>"> 
</form>
<form action="deleteproducts.php" method="post" class="text-center" id="deleteForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="text-center" value="<?=$product['sku']?>"> 
</form>
<form action="deleteproducts.php" method="post" class="text-center" id="deleteForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="text-center" value="<?=$product['sku']?>"> 
</form>
```

Each new `<form>` tag starts a new form, and your submit button is not part of any of them. When you hit `Submit` only the `Submit` button is submitted.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
<?php
$products = [
    ['sku'=>"product 1"],
    ['sku'=>"product 2"],
    ['sku'=>"product 3"],
    ['sku'=>"product 4"],

];

?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Mass Delete"><br>
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="text-center" value="<?=$product['sku']?>"><br> 
<?php  } ?>
</form>
```

The `<form>` wraps all the HTML used to create the table, including the `Submit` button and all the check boxes. When you hit `submit` the value of the `submit` button will be submitted, along with the values of all the active check boxes.

What you'll see in the `$_POST` array is something like this:

```
Array
(
[delete] => Mass Delete
[checkbox] => Array
(
[0] => product 1
[1] => product 3
)

)
```